# How do Ranking Window functions handle NULL values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to figure out how ranking functions in Redshift handle NULL values. I have with me some sample data that i am using to understand the behavior.

```
CREATE TABLE public.Employee
("ID" numeric(18,0),
Name VARCHAR(100),
RoleName VARCHAR(100),
Salary NUMERIC(18,0),
Salary2 numeric(20,0)
);
```

Inserting some dummy values

```
INSERT INTO public.Employee("ID",NAME,ROLENAME,SALARY,SALARY2) VALUES
(1, 'Alex', 'SuperAdmin', null,null ),
(2,'Thomas', 'Admin', 80000,null ),
(3, 'Peter', 'SuperAdmin', 95000,20444 ),
(4, 'Sid', 'SuperAdmin', 70000,45477),
(5, 'Maria', 'Admin', 60000,7685 ),
(6, 'Andrew', 'Manager', 50000,686754 ),
(7, 'Fedric', 'SuperAdmin', null,46342 ),
(8, 'Anton', 'Supervisor', null,967564 ),
(9, 'Mandy', 'Manager', 30000,7563452 )
```

If i run the following line of code

```
select ID,(salary - salary2) as sum_val ,rank() over (order by sum_val desc) as total_profit
from public.employee
```

My Outlooks looks something the following

```
id  sum_val total_profit
1       1
2       1
7       1
8       1
3   74556   5
5   52315   6
4   24523   7
6   -636754 8
9   -7533452    9
```

I wanted to understand

1. Why are null values automatically sorted first?
2. Is there a way to sort null values within the window function?

Comment: Could you please format your query output so that the output values line up with the columns? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are null values automatically sorted first?

Because that's [how Redshift works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html):

> NULLS values are treated as their own group, sorted and ranked according to the NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST option. By default, NULL values are sorted and ranked last in ASC ordering, and sorted and ranked first in DESC ordering.

---

> Is there a way to sort null values within the window function?

Sort them how?

If you want the NULL values to come last but share the same rank, use `NULLS LAST`:

```
SELECT  ID, (salary - salary2) AS sum_val, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum_val DESC NULLS LAST) AS total_profit
FROM    public.employee
```

If you want to add a secondary sort for NULL values, specify it in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT  ID, (salary - salary2) AS sum_val,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum_val DESC NULLS LAST, NVL2(sum_val, NULL, secondary_sort_condition_only_for_nulls)) AS total_profit
FROM    public.employee
```